# Adding roles to service accounts on Google Cloud Platform using REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam, service-accounts

I want to create a service account on GCP using a python script calling the REST API and then give it specific roles - ideally some of [these](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/viewing-grantable-roles), such as `roles/logging.logWriter`.

First I make a request to [create the account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create) which works fine and I can see the account in Console/IAM.
Second I want to give it the role and [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/setIamPolicy) seems like the right method. However, it is not accepting `roles/logging.logWriter`, saying HttpError 400, `"Role roles/logging.logWriter is not supported for this resource.">`
Conversely, if I set the desired policy in console, then try the `getIamPolicy` method (using the gcloud tool), all I get back is response `etag: ACAB`, no mention of the actual role I set. Hence I think these roles refer to different things.

Any idea how to go about scripting a role/scope for a service account using the API?

Comment: Quick note: If you don't have some sort of global roles, usually, set the roles for the thing ("principal")(service account here) in the permissions of the target (e.g. in Edit access of a bucket) - **don't get confused** -  the service account itself has permissions section but those are permission to "manage/view" the service account itself, ***not*** service account's permissions to other stuff :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can grant permissions to a GCP service account in a GCP project without having to rewrite the entire project policy!

Use the `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ...` command for that ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding)).

For example, given the environment variables `GCP_PROJECT_ID` and `GCP_SVC_ACC` the following command grants all privileges in the `container.admin` role to the chosen service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
    --member=serviceAccount:${GCP_SVC_ACC} \
    --role=roles/container.admin
```

To review what you've done:

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy $GCP_PROJECT_ID \
    --flatten="bindings[].members" \
    --format='table(bindings.role)' \
    --filter="bindings.members:${GCP_SVC_ACC}"
```

Output:

```
ROLE
roles/container.admin
```

(or more roles, if those were granted before)

Notes:

- The environment variable `GCP_SVC_ACC` is expected to contain the email notation for the service account.
- Kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485552/145400) for the nicely formatted readout.

Comment: Looks like there is a missing trailing backslash in the first `gcloud projects` command example on line 2.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! Looks like I fixed that but forgot to say thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You appear to be trying to set a role on the service account (as a resource). That's for setting who can use the service account.

If you want to give the service account (as an identity) a particular role on the project and its resources, see this method: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy

Comment: one should be extremely careful, the page starts with the following : Sets the IAM access control policy for the specified Project. **Overwrites any existing policy.**

Comment: Yes, get the existing policy first, modify it, then write it.

Comment: still wouldn't it be advisable to set serviceAccounts that would receive other serviceAccounts/users (the first sentence of your answer) ? this full overwrites feels extreme, a mistake can screw your whole project. To be honest, I'm finding it hard to understand those two correctly on gcloud; compared let's say to aws, where groups/users are more understandable. Feels safer, you can toggle a user from a group. May I ask you if a comparable pattern exists on gcloud ?

Comment: @ben were you able to do it in a safer way?

Comment: Nope; gave up and went further on aws

Comment: // , I got the same error when trying to GET the associated role. I run into this BS any time I try to use GCP without Terraform. `gcloud` has a looooot of little gotchas.

Comment: // , `ACAB` is some real trash as far as UX. If GCP were actually popular I'd nominate it as this generation of DevOps' `PC Load Letter` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw-8oEO8bZo

Comment: Using `projects add-iam-policy-binding` seems to be a less risky, more viable, easier to use solution to the given problem. I have added a new answer, please review!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it to multiple:

```
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in $PROJECTS; do
    gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
        --member=serviceAccount:terraform@$PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
        --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
done
```