# service account does not have storage.objects.get access for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I have created a service account in Google Cloud Console and selected role `Storage` / `Storage Admin` (i.e. full control of GCS resources).

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy my_project` seems to [indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006062) that the role was actually selected:

```
- members:
  - serviceAccount:my_sa@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:my_sa@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:my_sa@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectCreator
```

And [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) clearly indicates that role `roles/storage.admin` comprises permissions `storage.objects.*` (as well as `storage.buckets.*`).

But when I try using that service account in conjunction with the Google Cloud Storage Client Library for Python, I receive this error message:

> my_sa@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have
>   storage.objects.get access to my_project/my_bucket.

So why would the selected role not be sufficient in this context?

Comment: Could you share the code you're using?
Also could you tell me more about how this service account is set to be used by the client library?

Comment: @FrankNatividad This is what questions (and upvotes) are for. Why not post such a question (and link to it from here, so that I can notice it as well)?

Comment: It looks there's a bug in gcloud. I've come across the same problem. Roles assigned but always permission denied from the command line, which dissapeared after removing service account and creating another one.

Comment: In case this helps anyone in the future: I had a similar problem but had to reboot my IDE (PyCharm) after granting the correct permissions.

Comment: Quick note: the role has to be assigned ***on the bucket*** (***not*** in the Service account's permission tab ...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem was apparently that the service account was associated with too many roles, perhaps as a results of previous configuration attempts.

These steps resolved the issue:

- removed all (three) roles for the offending service account (member) `my_sa` under `IAM & Admin` / `IAM`
- deleted `my_sa` under `IAM & Admin` / `Service accounts`
- recreated `my_sa` (again with role `Storage` / `Storage Admin`)

Effects are like this:

- `my_sa` shows up with one role (`Storage Admin`) under `IAM & Admin` / `IAM`
- `my_sa` shows up as member under `Storage` / `Browser` / `my_bucket` / `Edit bucket permissions`

Comment: Happy to hear you solved the issue. Principally, if a service account has Storage Admin role it should be able to create a bucket no matter what additional roles it has. I try to reproduce this issue, having a service account with three roles storage.admin, storage.objectAdmin, and storage.objectCreator; I confirm I can create a bucket using that service account. Can you double check by adding these additional roles if the issue still continues on your side?

Answer (score 35):

Go to your bucket's permissions section and open add permissions section for your bucket. For example, insufficient service, which gcloud tells you, is;

```
1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Add this service as user then give these roles;

- Cloud Storage - Storage Admin
- Cloud Storage - Storage Object Admin
- Cloud Storage - Storage Object Creator

Then you should have sufficient permissions to make changes on your bucket.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. While my actual username was added with all the permissions, it worked only when I added 1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com this principal

Answer (score 23):

It's worth noting, that **you need to wait up to a few minutes** for permissions to be working in case you just assigned them. At least that's what happened to me after:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding xxx --member
"serviceAccount:xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/storage.objectViewer"
```

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me with fresh app engine deployment via `gcloud app deploy`.

Answer (score 4):

I just realized this happens some times when you are just creating the Firebase/Firestore/Storage project by first time.

If you got this error in your first installation/deploy/setup, just wait 1 minute and try again.
Seems like some delays in the Google Cloud deploys/serving are responsible of this.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it worked after I added the associated email in the IAM page by the folowing steps. ChatGPT helps me on this btw.

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console at https://console.cloud.google.com/.
2. Select the project associated with your Firebase project.
3. Open the "IAM & admin" page from the left-hand menu.
4. Click the "ADD" button to add a new member to the project.
5. Enter the email address. For me it was in the following format. `firebase-adminsdk-xxxxx@xxxxx-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
6. Select the role `Storage Object Creator` or `Storage Object Admin` from the dropdown menu.
7. Click the "SAVE" button to save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because deployed with the `"default-bucket"` as parameter needed for the storage emulator.

```js
admin.storage().bucket('default-bucket'); // do not deploy that
```

To fix it, I set the default bucket name at the initialization of the firebase admin.

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const config = process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR ? {
    storageBucket: 'default-bucket',
} : {
    storageBucket: 'YOUT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET',
};

admin.initializeApp(config);

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
```

Comment: I had the same issue! I had all the proper permissions, but using the wrong bucket name resulted in a "permission" error, which was pretty misleading.

Comment: I mean... in google's defense... there might be a bucket named "default-bucket", and you don't have access to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I copied a cloud function from another project because I forgot to update the storage bucket. Silly mistake.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  storageBucket: "gs://*****.appspot.com",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, after the service account is created, interface returns error: "service account does not have storage.objects.get access for Google Cloud Storage".

But, When I tried again the next day, everything was fine :)

Comment: I am having the same issue, @fgd. In GCP I've set `Storage Object Admin` permissions, however I am using Firebase Storage instead.