# Firebase Cloud Functions deploy error. SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have tried to deploy Firebase Cloud Functions in order to delete users.

but I got an error.

> Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate
> manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Cannot use import
> statement outside a module

The source code is below.

(functions/node_modules/index.js)

```
import functions = require("firebase-functions");
import admin = require("firebase-admin");

// firebase-adminの初期化
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUser = functions
    .region("asia-northeast1")
    .firestore.document("deleted_users/{docId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const deleteDocument = snap.data();
      const uid = deleteDocument.uid;

      // Authenticationのユーザーを削除する
      await admin.auth().deleteUser(uid);
    });
```

Does anyone know why this error happens?

Comment: Try `const` instead of `import` in first 2 lines.

Comment: Thank you.
I guess It works.
but I still have an error" HTTP Error: 403, <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>service-799047667557@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>
"

Comment: It's still a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410633/service-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-access-for-google-cloud-storag