# iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy is required to perform this operation on service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

From:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts

running this command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy \
    mysa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I get:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy mysa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.get-iam-policy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/mysa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

But I do have `iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy` permission on the current user(role Owner)?

Comment: Are you specifying the **Service Account** (listed in your project) correctly? [Link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=)

Comment: Yes, I use the name listed in service accounts

Comment: Or "Email" column

Comment: Try running the `gcloud auth list` command. Is the active account set the correct one (the one that has the Owner role)?

Comment: Yes the current user is "Owner", already did that - good suggestion.

Comment: It's strange as it should be sufficient to get the policy with that command. The only time I was able to get exactly the same error is when the service account I specified was wrong (e.g. **not a [service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=)** or had a **typo** in it).

Comment: I will investigate if something else is causing this error and will inform you.

Comment: Thanks man, I will let you know if I find the solution

Comment: Just found it, see my answer. Thanks again, if you want to describe / give a better answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear the issue was solved, Chris!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the email member(Service Account email) to the project - in IAM users.

When I deleted this (SA member) in IAM,
it worked giving "etag: ACAB" as a result.

I Need to figure out what that is, but it worked. Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006062/how-do-i-list-the-roles-associated-with-a-gcp-service-account)

This account, should maybe have been deleted automatically when deleting a Service Account - but what do I know :-)

Comment: `etag: ACAB` means that you have not assigned a role to the service account yet - [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#viewing-roles)

Comment: @DenisT. - That is not correct. The `ACAB` is a token that is used to track updates and does not represent an empty service account role list. When you modify the roles, the tag will change. If you try to update the roles with an incorrect tag, the request will fail.

Comment: Thanks, John. That's right, the output will show only an `etag` value if you haven't assigned a role to the service account.