# Terraform Firebase Web Application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have some trouble with this terraform file I wrote to define a Firebase application in my org account:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.86.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = file("service-account-credentials.json")
  project     = var.gcp_project_id
  region      = var.region
  zone        = var.zone
}

resource "google_project" "default" {
    provider = google-beta

    project_id = var.gcp_project_id
    name       = "Optic OTP API"
    org_id     = var.gcp_organization_id
}

resource "google_firebase_project" "default" {
    provider = google-beta
    project  = google_project.default.project_id
}

resource "google_firebase_web_app" "basic" {
    provider = google-beta
    project = google_project.default.project_id
    display_name = "Optic OTP API"

    depends_on = [google_firebase_project.default]
}

data "google_firebase_web_app_config" "basic" {
  provider   = google-beta
  web_app_id = google_firebase_web_app.basic.app_id
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "default" {
    provider = google-beta
    name = "firebase-optic-storage"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
    provider = google-beta
    bucket = google_storage_bucket.default.name
    name = "firebase-config.json"

    content = jsonencode({
        appId              = google_firebase_web_app.basic.app_id
        apiKey             = data.google_firebase_web_app_config.basic.api_key
        authDomain         = data.google_firebase_web_app_config.basic.auth_domain
        databaseURL        = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.basic, "database_url", "")
        storageBucket      = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.basic, "storage_bucket", "")
        messagingSenderId  = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.basic, "messaging_sender_id", "")
        measurementId      = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.basic, "measurement_id", "")
    })
}
```

I followed the official [terraform plugin documentation here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/firebase_web_app)

I’m using a Service Account created in the company GCP org within the `Firebase Service Management Service Agent` role:

[image: roles]

But when I run `terraform plan` I get

```
Error when reading or editing Storage Bucket "firebase-optic-storage": googleapi: Error 403: XXX does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

Even if the service account’s role has it!

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy optic-web-otp

# returns
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:XXX
  role: roles/firebase.managementServiceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:XXX
  role: roles/firebase.sdkAdminServiceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:XXX
  role: roles/firebase.sdkProvisioningServiceAgent
- members:
  - user:MY-EMAIL
  role: roles/owner
etag: 
version: 1
```

(The `XXX` is the right service account identifier)

Do you have some hints to check what is missing from my Service Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the roles that you listed are the only ones that your account has - you lack roles that allow you to access Cloud Storage.** Command you used to check the roles doesn't give you correct information.

Correct solution (described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485552/12257250)) would be to run this :

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <your project name>  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:<your account name>"
```

If you don't see any of these roles:

- `roles/storage.objectAdmin`
- `roles/storage.admin`
- `roles/storage.objectCreator`

described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) you won't be able to create any buckets/objects.

In this case [add these roles to your service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant-single-role) and try again.

For example:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding optic-web-otp \
    --member=user:my-user@example.com --role=roles/roles/storage.admin
```