# gcloud get-iam-policy not showing full list of principals and their roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I noticed that my `gcloud projects get-iam-policy {project_id} --format=json` gave a slightly different result compared to the IAM list in the GCP management console, when the same project is set.

For example, I am expecting a few principals to have roles like  "viewer", "Storage Admin", "Tag Administrator", "Tag User", "Project Mover" based on the console. Those are not shown in the output of gcloud cli. I logged in to my work account in the console so I am sure that both are having equal permission.

Next, I ran the gcloud command again but this time setting project_id to org_id. I could get some of the mentioned roles above from other projects.

What have i done incorrectly? Or could it be a gcp bug?

[Update] As requested, here is a censored sample showing the difference between CLI result and GCP Console. In the CLI formatted result, I filtered the list down to all roles that are associated to my org, folder and project, because some roles are inheritable and I just want to make sure all are captured. On the other hand, the GCP console is set specifically to my project.

So logically, the GCP console result should be a subset of the more complete CLI result. But some roles (boxed in red) are not present in the CLI result.

[image: Comparison between CLI formatted result vs IAM list in GCP console]

I thought maybe this was a role-specific issue, so i unfiltered my CLI result. I could see other users/principals having that role.

Comment: The Google Cloud console UI shows inherited members. Double-check the hierarchy for where IAM roles are bound. The CLI shows the IAM policy for a resource (the project resource). The CLI shows more details that are merged. Are your projects part of a Google Cloud organization?

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes its part of an org, and the right org. Yes I am aware that the CLI console list includes inherited permissions, so what I did was running get-iam-policy on org level. I didnt see some of the roles in the cli list.

Comment: Please show an example using the CLI and a screenshot using the GUI.

Comment: @JohnHanley Screenshot is attached in the question. Basically I compared the result between the two and found that GCP console has some roles that are not present in the CLI list. This shouldnt be the case because I have filtered the CLI list to show all roles that are associated to the org, folder and project that my console is currently set to.

Comment: Nice graphic. Please include the CLI command that you used and a screenshot from the GUI.  As a suggestion, you have a few IAM roles that are not required because the identity has the Owner role. However, that is not the real problem. I am wondering if the 24 roles listed is a limitation of the CLI (not fetching all roles - pagination issue?). Which version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: I recommend creating a bug report. Go to this [page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and search for the link ***Create new Google Cloud CLI issue***.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am running Google Cloud SDK 445.0.0. I extract role list using gcloud projects get-iam-policy {project_id/org_id/folder_id} command. Alright, will follow your suggestion and raise a report. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are currently observing that `gcloud` gave a slightly different result compared to that of the IAM list in the GCP console might be due to permissions issues. Also ensure that you are using the same credentials.

For the custom role in a Project, try running:

```
gcloud iam roles list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name)"
```

Or

```
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  gcloud iam roles list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(name)"
Done
```

**UPDATE:**

Try running

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR GCLOUD PROJECT>  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:<YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT>"
```

Comment: You can also refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006062/how-do-i-list-the-roles-associated-with-a-gcp-service-account) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, I can confirm that I have my account set as the active account on CLI, as per shown when I ran gcloud auth list --filter=status:ACTIVE

Comment: I have run the gcloud iam roles list that you suggested. Its generating only one entry (one role).

Comment: Try running updated command also please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006062/how-do-i-list-the-roles-associated-with-a-gcp-service-account).